# Authentication on a REST API in Power BI

Tags: json, rest, powerbi

I would like to use Power BI to query data obtained through a REST API. This requires initial authentication with a username and password throuhg a dedicated endpoint, which returns an authentication token in a JSON response.

This token then must be passed in the header of subsequent calls. Is this possible in Power BI? I couldn't find any obvious way to first authenticate, store the results in a variable to be reused to get the data.

Thanks!